# Need difference between power rails,voltage rail and current rail

Tags: power-supply

Can anyone please explain the difference between power rails , voltage rails and current rails?.How do we choose between these rails?

Answer (score 1):

They are probably all the same but different people in different circumstances call them different names to suit what they are trying to achieve or describe.

For instance, I would use "power rail" or "voltage rail" without thinking it would confuse anyone. The basic "voltage rail" implies the connections to a voltage source but, when you start drawing current (via those rails) from the voltage source, you are (likely) also drawing power. P = V*I.

So suddenly, a voltage rail has also become a power rail.

"Current rail" is a bit outside my vocabulary because I would only use the terms voltage or power rails but, if a voltage rail is passing current, it could be described as a current rail but, I would prefer to call it a power or voltage rail.

Comment: "Current rail" could be a power rail connected to a constant current source instead of a constant voltage source.

Comment: @Majenko - have you ever seen one described this way?

Comment: Nope, that's why I said "could be"...  Of course, it could also mean "the power rail I'm currently pointing to"... ;)

Comment: @Majenko have you ever seen a current source? :P

Comment: @VladimirCravero Yes. An LM317 with shunt resistor between OUT and ADJ for constant current mode.  Constant current sources are very common for battery charging applications etc.

Comment: Yeah I was just joking, I also thought of the "currently pointing to" thing but you stole it :D

Comment: You guys LOL!!!

Comment: @VladimirCravero Have you ever seen a currant sauce?

Comment: http://altnursery.ie/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Redcurrant-169x120.jpg

Comment: Yeah everybody is so dead serious around here, I imagine that's part of the game... But sometimes I can't help and say some bull***t.